# How can I assign hex string to a char[] variable?

Tags: c++, hex, arrays

Assume my hex string. `hexStr = "aecf"`

How can I assign the hex string value to `unsigned char myChar[]` as below. Thanks.

```
myChar[0] = 0xae;
myChar[1] = 0xcf;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may convert data as follows:

```
    char* hexstr="aecf";
    int hexsize=strlen(hexstr);
    unsigned char* myChar = new unsigned char[hexsize/2+1];
    myChar[hexsize/2]='\0'
    for (int i=0,intj=0;i<hexsize;i+=2,j++)
    {
        int tmp;
        sscanf(hexstr+i, "%2x",&tmp));
        myChar[j]=tmp; // warning, ignore it
    }
```

this is in case you do not use static strings, otherwise use other answers.

Comment: `char* hexstr = "aecf"` is deprecated in standard C++. Has been for about 15 years. And why all the illegible C pointer hackery?

Comment: write your own answer. If you see the question, return tupe should be unsigned char*. so what's the trouble of using pointers?

Comment: I have a professional duty to point out when people write inaccurate answers. `char* hexstr = "aecf"` is both deprecated and dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

```
char myChar[] = { 0xAE, 0xCF };
```

There is no magic that will make a string literal read as binary unless you parse it yourself, there is however the old fashion array literals which given C's weak typing always seem to work in a lot of situations.

Comment: C has a static weak typing type system which was what I was refering to. In contrast to strongly typed languages such as Haskell, C let's you get away with a lot of sinister things.

Comment: @John: Correct. It is a static weakly typed language. How that could ever translate to "typeless" is ... baffling.

Comment: I've heard other people refer to it as such and it isn't that far off from the truth. However, I'm no avid C programmer and I occasionaly do make the careless remark that some frown upon. My bad.

Comment: @John: It's hilariously far from the truth. :)

Comment: Care to explain instead of throwing sarcasm in the mix? The compiler isn't exactly known for being especially type safe. I believe there's more merit to my answer than you give credit for.

Comment: @John: Where did I employ sarcasm? (Hint: nowhere). There is nothing "typeless" about C, period. As you stated yourself, it has a type system. "Typeless" implies no type system, or fully dynamic typing.

Answer (score 2):

Are you starting with a string, then trying to convert it over to a byte array? If so , copy the string, appending a \x for every 2 characters. String litterals can have \x in them to denote a hexadecimal character, as in 
    myStringLitterial = "\xAE\xCF";

Comment: But you're changing the question by using a different input string.

Comment: yes, indeed i was, but the question seemed to me more like he was trying to send that data over a socket (hence unsigned char type) and he needed the bytes sent over the wire to match a AE CF. Just a thought.

Comment: `unsigned char` is used for more than just sockets. But, yes, we need to know his wider goals in order to answer this question adequately.

Answer (score 0):

C-ish way (using std::sprintf):

```
#include <cstdio>
/* ... */
const char *hexStr = "aecf";
unsigned char myChar[3];
std::sprintf (myChar, "%02x%02x", hexStr);
```

Comment: Change `<stdio.h>` to `<cstdio>` and don't forget the `using namespace std;`...  That's pretty much it.  Is it inflexible?  Yes.  Should it be?  It depends on the circumstance (fixed-length record vs a variable-length string of hex digits).  In any case, it is only an example.

Comment: If you know how to make it C++, make it C++! Otherwise, it's not a fit for this question. (And, please, no `using namespace std;`... ugh)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `hexStr` has even number length and `myChar` has sufficient
size, does the following code meet the purpose
(though `strtol` is a C function)?

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
  std::string hexStr = "aecf";
  unsigned char myChar[2];

  for ( unsigned i = 0;  i < hexStr.size();  i += 2 )
    myChar[ i / 2 ] = strtol( hexStr.substr( i, 2 ).c_str(), 0, 16 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same thing and after reading a lot, finally created this function

```
// in = "63 09  58  81" 
void hexatoascii(char *in, char* out, int len){
    char buf[5000];
    int i,j=0;
    char * data[5000];
    printf("\n size %d", strlen(in));
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(in); i+=2)
    {
        data[j] = (char*)malloc(8);
        if (in[i] == ' '){
            i++;
        }
        else if(in[i + 1] == ' '){
            i++;
        }
        printf("\n %c%c", in[i],in[i+1]);
        sprintf(data[j], "%c%c", in[i], in[i+1]);
        j++;
    }
    //printf("\n data %c", data);
    for (i = 0; i < j-1; i++){
        int tmp;
        printf("\n data %s", data[i] );
        sscanf(data[i], "%2x", &tmp);
        out[i] = tmp;
    }
    //printf("\n ascii value of hexa %s", out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered the same in a duplicate... but may be someone will find it useful here, a C++ish

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


int main() {
    std::string myStr = "1122AA010A";

    std::stringstream ss;
    int n;
    for(int i = 0; i<myStr.length(); ) {
        std::istringstream(myStr.substr(i,2))>>std::hex>>n;
        ss<<(char)n;
        i += 2;
        }

    std::string result = ss.str();
    //could also use ss.str().c_str() to get the c-ish result

    std::cout<<"\n"<<result<<"\n";
    return 0;
    }
```